# Creating a Silverlight Assembly

Tags: silverlight, assemblies

Okay, about three to four months ago, while looking for something COMPLETELY different, I was tripping over how-to's on creating Silverlight assemblies. Now that I am actually looking for that info, I can't seem to find it.

Can anyone point me to some resources for taking a UserControl I've created and making an assembly from it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Silverlight library in Visual Studio, and add your UserControl to that project.

When you build, it will generate an assembly for you.

Comment: Wow, that was simple! Thanks!